# NoMethodError when method is returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two methods which are used to determine whether to apply a class to the page to show that something is overdue and needs attention.

I'm getting an error when a brand new user registers:

```
undefined method `last_contact_done_date=' for #<User:0x6183708>
```

The line that it's referencing the error to is this:

```
2:   <div class="span3 <%= "overdue" if (signed_in? && contact_overdue?(current_user.id)) %>">
```

The `contact_overdue?` method is this (in a home page helper)

```
def contact_overdue?(user_id)
  @user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
  return true if (Date.today - (@user.last_contact_done_date ||= Date.tomorrow)) > 6
end
```

and the last_contact_done_date method is this in the `User` model

```
  def last_contact_done_date
      self.contacts.order('date_done DESC').first.try(:date_done)
  end
```

I thought that if I was using the `||=` operator in the `contact_overdue?` method, then I would return -1 if the `last_contact_done_date` is `nil`. But it appears that's not working. What operator should I be using in `last_contact_done_date` or how should I change the `contact_overdue?` method so that if there are no contacts, then `false` is returned from the `contact_overdue?` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the default value of `-1` when there is no last contact done date, use

```
@user.last_contact_done_date || -1
```

(it is unreasonable to expect `Date.tomorrow` to return `-1` ;) )

`||=` is an assignment operator; `a ||= b` is equivalent to `a = a || b`; and if `a` is an attribute (i.e. is prefixed with a dot and an instance, `c.a`), assignment to it will call the method `a=`. Thus, your code necessitates that you have a method named `last_contact_done_date=` to handle the assignment, which you don't.

Comment: What is the method with = at the end called? I need to know so I can read more and understand it better.

Comment: If you're asking about `last_contact_done_date=`, then attribute setter, or attribute writer - as opposed to attribute getters/readers. Both are collectively known as attribute accessors, or properties (the former is Ruby lingo, the latter more universal). http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Using-Attributes.htm goes a bit over it. If you're asking about `||=` (which is not actually a method), it's one of augmented or compound assignment operators, read here for a general overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment. It is specifically called conditional assignment operator in Ruby.